# Spring Boot + Security: No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header when setting allowed origins

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, cors, response-headers

I'm using Spring Boot v2.1.1.RELEASE together with Spring Security and am trying to log into the application via REST.

I have a configuration file which implements `WebMvcConfigurer` so I can override the addCorsMappings method:

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(final CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**");
}
```

This works fine; I can send my login data to `http://localhost:8080/login` and get a normal Response back, with session cookie and all:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 20 Jan 2019 13:14:46 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=66B74AE4F547BA77604AE199E0A48D7E; Path=/; HttpOnly
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Mind the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.
However, if I specify the allowed origins as follows, the Response does not include the formerly mentioned header:

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(final CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("localhost");
}
```

Will result in the Response:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 20
Date: Sun, 20 Jan 2019 13:15:15 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

It doesn't matter which origin I am allowing; "http://localhost", "http://example.com" and "example.com" all lead to the same result.

While debugging, I noticed that the authentication process stops at the CorsFilter when I include the `allowedOrigins` bit in the code.

This is all about the login process! I can't use the `@CrossOrigin` annotation (as far as I'm aware) because I have no method to put it on.

I am testing the REST login with this script: https://pastebin.com/YezC3wWr

Is this a bug in Spring or by design? Am I missing something here?

**EDIT**: The "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header in the response is only sent if the request is sent from an allowed origin, and that was NOT the case. I was hosting the HTML test file on `http://localhost:8000`, so I had to add **this exact URL** to the allowed origins on the server. Not `localhost`, not `localhost:8000` but `http://localhost:8000`. The authentication then succeeds and the header is also included in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running the HTML page on the same domain as the login request, there will be no `Origin` header in request, thus no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.
Is this the case with your code? do you run the HTML file under `http://localhost:8080/` ?

If no, please post the error from the browser's console.
Also, would be great if you can post both request and response headers

Answer (score 0):

Try using "http://localhost:8080".
Do you test it via web browser or POST directly for example with Postman?

Comment: That url doesn't work either. I'm testing it via web browser with the following HTML file: https://pastebin.com/YezC3wWr

Comment: After lunching your html file, open browser console and navigate to Network section. Then reload page and try to login. Did the OPTIONS request pass?

Comment: It does not do any OPTIONS request (which is strange?), neither with allowed origins nor without. Only one POST request to `http://localhost:8080/login`.

Comment: Try adding xhr.setRequestHeader("Origin", "http://localhost:8080") to your html file.
Also please check the result of POST login call using Postman.

Comment: Found the problem, I was hosting the HTML file on `http://localhost:8000`, not 8080. When I add that to the allowed origins, everything's fine.